# Sum on Count in HiveQL

Tags: sql, hiveql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8srK9.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7Gx7.png)I am new to HiveQL. Here is my problem. I have employees terminated/retired and there will be multiple termination for same employee in a same time period, after rehire and I need to calculate the sum(terminations). Below is my query..
HiveQL

```
select employee_id, Date, work_dept_c, Emp_type, mlvl_n,
       (case when work_dept_c in (1,2,3,4,5) and emp_type not in ('S') and mlvl_n not in (T') then count(employee_id) else 0 end) as Countofemployee
from tablex
where date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-06-01'
group by work_dept_c, emp_type, mlvl_n, employee_id, date
```

this above query works and gives me count of employees id terminated but it does not give me the total sum of same employee if they were terminated twice in same time period where they were hired again in same period, basically I need to get 2 termination count... I tried to put Sum but it does not work... kindly help and let me know if I am not clear

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be really helpful.

Comment: edit the question and use a SQL Fiddle please, comments like above are useless and unreadable

Comment: added sample data and expected result image